# Connection to Simpro API not working - Tivoka send is failing

Tags: php, api, oauth, json-rpc

I'm having trouble connecting to our Simpro server via the API.

I am using a slightly modified version of the directaccessexample.php as per the Simpro GIT repository here - https://github.com/simPRO-Software/simpro-api-php

My server PHP version is 5.6.32

My composer is loading the below packages:
{
    "require": {
        "monolog/monolog": "*",
                "eher/OAuth": "1.0.*",
                "tivoka/tivoka": "3.1.0",
        "psr/log":"*"
    }
}

In my attempts to debug, the Client.php script (as provided by the Simpro GIT) appears to fail at specifically the send call from the below lines:

```
$rpcRequest = new \Tivoka\Client\Request($method, $args);
$this->connection->send($rpcRequest);
```

I have identified this by outputting to error_log above and below this line - the code appears to die in the function on the send request (and therefore never reaches the second error_log output. There is no error logged that I can see which I find bizarre, it just appears to exit the function.

I am not seeing any other errors in any php error log/apache log/etc, and I've ruled out the issue being the firewall on my server.

I am wondering if this is a problem with versions of PHP or the installed packages from composer - though I have tried a couple of different specific versions without any luck (no change to php version, however).

From the above code, the json_encoded output of $rpcRequest is:

```
{"id":"7b0911cc-dd67-4032-b810-474e549edecc","method":"CompanySearch","params":["%"],"request":null,"response":null,"result":null,"error":null,"errorMessage":null,"errorData":null,"responseHeaders":null,"responseHeadersRaw":null}
```

Can anybody assist here? I am pulling my hair out. I'm aware I could attempt to write my own code using different oauth/rpc packages but I am not that advanced with PHP.

Thanks,
Justin.